# How can I combine two Unicode characters into one

Tags: arrays, swift, string, character

Here's what I mean:

```
let desiredResult: Character = "ї\u{0308}\u{20dd}"

let first: Character = "ї\u{0308}"
let combinedResult: Character = Array("\(first)\u{20dd}".characters)[0]
```

How can I write this mess in more a elegant way?

Answer (score 1):

Just toss the `String` into the `Character` initializer:

```
let result = Character("\(first)\u{20dd}")
```

Comment: Thanx, I have been frustrated Xcode could not infer proper type in such code:

let result: Character = "\(first)\u{20dd}"


Casting is required

Comment: @user3567929 That has nothing to do with inference. You can't convert a string to a character. The initializer call has to be explicit.